# How to get macOS Mojave Style Dark Mode in Java in a Swing Application?

Tags: java, macos, macos-mojave

I want to know if there is some way to get macOS Mojave style Dark Mode in a swing application in Java?

I want to get macOS Mojave Style Dark Mode on a JFrame in a Java Swing Application.

Please let me know.

Thanks

Asrar Bashir Sunge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess, you might give it a try to use Darcula:

https://github.com/Revivius/nb-darcula

https://github.com/bulenkov/Darcula

```
import com.bulenkov.darcula.*;
...
...
BasicLookAndFeel darculaLookAndFeel = new DarculaLaf();
try {
  UIManager.setLookAndFeel(darculaLookAndFeel);
} catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
  // ups!
}
```

### [image]

Comment: That's nice for some cases, but it's not integrated with macOS. The title bar stays in light mode, and the app is stuck in "dark mode" when it should be responding to system theme changes. It also doesn't feel like a native app at all anymore since it's using the Darcula controls.

Comment: @BaptisteCandellier the title bar can be fixed via https://stackoverflow.com/a/56487943/3196753.

Comment: Is there a way to fix it via code?

Answer (score 10):

It seems the official solution to get dark mode is to use a system property. From [JDK-8235363](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8235363), this is available from JDK 14 and later:

> A new system property is added: `"apple.awt.application.appearance"` to set the appearance of the whole java application.
>
> - If no value is set then light mode will be used
> - if `"system"` value is set then the current appearance of the macOS will be used
> - Other possible values are `"NSAppearanceNameAqua"` (the same as light), or `"NSAppearanceNameDarkAqua"` (requesting dark) See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsappearancenameaqua?language=objc
> - If an incorrect value is set then light mode will be used

To get the best user experience, you should probably always use the `system` value, to match the user's preferred setting:

```
-Dapple.awt.application.appearance=system
```

And of course test and make sure that you don't have your self-defined colors that makes text or components invisible or hard to see with this color scheme.

---

PS: If you are also looking for a Swing Look and Feel that matches the native macOS dark mode, have a look at [VAqua](https://violetlib.org/vaqua/darkmode.html). Disclaimer: I've never used it in a real application, but it looks extremely nice and uses native rendering to look just like the real thing.

Comment: `system` didn't work for me but `NSAppearanceNameAqua` and `NSAppearanceNameDarkAqua` did.

Comment: @IndianaKernick Strange. Has worked fine for me. What Java version? And how did it not work (ie. Exception? Crash? No effect?)?

Comment: I'm using Java 15 and macOS 10.13.1. It had no effect (showed light themed window). I would have preferred `system` but meh.  `NSAppearanceNameDarkAqua` is fine for my purposes.

Comment: At time of writing this (JDK 16.0.1, JDK 15.0.2), I can't get any of the recommended approaches to work (Tried `=system`, `=NSAppearanceNameDarkAqua`).   Source code is here: https://gist.github.com/tresf/8d682cb4f0d56945c1c3132e9e7864c7.  I'm setting the properties via IntelliJ's JVM properties.  I'm on an M1 Mac, testing using Azul's build, if that matters.

Comment: I believe that matters. I only tested on Oracle builds. But it’s implemented in OpenJDK, so it could work. I guess you have to ask Azul why it doesn’t.

Comment: On corretto 11.0.14.9.1, using `System.setProperty("apple.awt.application.appearance", "system")` appears to work. At least for the dark title bar (upon launch), the Look and Feel is still the regular Swing if it's not specifically customized. Also LaF and system bar won't change when the system UI changes. It needs something more involved, like this [darklaf](https://github.com/weisJ/darklaf/), and properly configured.

Answer (score 6):

Most recently, it seems the only working solution is:

```
java -Dapple.awt.application.appearance="system" -jar myapp.jar
```

... however for some older combinations of OpenJDK + macOS, to get the dark Title Bar, launch with option [`-NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance False`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsappearancecustomization/choosing_a_specific_appearance_for_your_macos_app#2993818).  For example:

```
java -jar myapp.jar -NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance False
       #  ("false", "no" or "0" will also work)
```

The above techniques can be safely combined for maximum compatibility.

**Note:** Many solutions recommend editing the `Info.plist` file, but those solutions didn't work for me.

**Warning:** Some frameworks [can crash as a result of forcing this](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=540357) so use with caution.

[image]

Comment: Since this is passed as a program argument, it might be necessary to ignore arg `-NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance` and its immediate adjacent value `False` or `No` or `0` case insensitively. You'll then might see this system log `2022-01-31 10:14:21.435 java[66993:2679574] NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance=NO`